# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'immer/dist/immer'

Tags: node.js, npm, immer.js

I am getting this error

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'immer/dist/immer'

even though immer's version in package.json and immer's version as a redux-toolkit dependency are same and I have got use-immer installed as well.

This is link to my package.json
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H2O9A18fPyB_xawzyR-NPUV8dTOukNvn/view?usp=sharing

This is link to my package-lock.json
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_eC4izxcnhw9ns3Ji7bnfsHzc0hyXZA1/view?usp=sharing

my redux store file

```js
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import ShowSideBar from '../Reducers/ShowSideBar';
import AddNewBoardB from '../Reducers/AddNewBoardB';
import Boards from '../Reducers/Boards';
import AddNewTask from '../Reducers/AddNewTask';
import EditBoard from '../Reducers/EditBoard';
import SetTaskView from '../Reducers/SetTaskView';
import Columns from '../Reducers/Columns';
import { enableMapSet } from 'immer';

enableMapSet();

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ShowSideBar:ShowSideBar,
    AddNewBoardB: AddNewBoardB,
    Boards:Boards,
    Columns:Columns,
    AddNewTask:AddNewTask,
    EditBoard:EditBoard,
    TaskView:SetTaskView,
})

export const Store = configureStore({
    reducer : rootReducer,
});
```

Edited : now I am getting this error

Uncaught Error: [Immer] The plugin for 'MapSet' has not been loaded into Immer. To enable the plugin, import and call `enableMapSet()` when initializing your application.

even though my dependency immer version and Redux-toolkit's immer version are same. I followed Taiwei tuan's advice but still getting this error.

Comment: Try removing the `package-lock.json` and the entire `node_modules/` directory, then try `npm i` and `npm audit fix` and try again to see if the error goes away first.

Comment: @TaiweiTuan followed your advice bit issue still not resolved

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: The version of immer in redux-toolkit and react-dev-utils, do you people think because of this reason I am getting above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved.

I actually need to call the enableMapSet in the reducer's slice file in which I am assigning a new set to reducer slice.
I am having a sub state in which I am assigning a new set to initial sub state value in which's file I need to call enableMapSet

Sub State - Columns.jsx

```html
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { enableMapSet } from "immer";
enableMapSet();
const Columns = createSlice({
    name:"Columns",
    initialState : new Set(),
    reducers : {
        AddColumn(state,action){
            state = new Set(...state, ...action.payload);
        }
    }
});

export const { AddColumn } = Columns.actions;

export default Columns.reducer;
```